# How to align text vertical in <a> element, that is displayed as block

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 231px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0275d8;
  border: 1px solid #0275d8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font: 16px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">some text</a>
</br>
<a href="#">some text that is bigger than in the first link</a>
```

Is there any way I could align the text vertically? Using paddings here is not a good idea, IMHO. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` and align text with `align-items: center`.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 231px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0275d8;
  border: 1px solid #0275d8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font: 16px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">some text</a>
<br>
<a href="#">some text that is bigger than in the first link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I tried this solution, but without `justify-content: center;`, so I thought it is a wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I always use a flexbox for this sort of thing. It is amazing for laying out content with css.  Here's [a great reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for flexbox.

In this case, you just need to add `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`, and remove `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`.

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 231px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0275d8;
  border: 1px solid #0275d8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font: 16px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>some text</span></a>
</br>
<a href="#"><span>some text that is bigger than in the first link</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

i recommend u to change to `display:table` and add a table cell inside, u can use any tag, like an `span`

```css
a {
  display: table;
  width: 231px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #0275d8;
  border: 1px solid #0275d8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font: 16px 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
a span{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>some text</span></a>
</br>
<a href="#"><span>some text that is bigger than in the first link</span></a>
```

`display:flex` doesnt work in all navigators, table & table cell are the best option to "vertical align" things inside a container